# Computing Fourier Transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, dirac-delta

I want to compute the fourier Transform of the form:

$$ y =[cos(w_ot)+cos(2w_ot)]x(t)$$ where the fourier transform of $x(t)$ is given as: 
\begin{equation}
{X(jw)}=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{w_o}[\frac{w}{w_o}+1]  & \text{if $ -1<= w/w_o <= 0$}\\
\frac{1}{w_o}[-\frac{w}{w_o}+1]  & \text{if $ -1<= w/w_o <= 0$}\\
0 & \text{else}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
My attempt:

I computed the fourier transform of $f(t)= [cos(w_ot)+cos(2w_ot)]$. Since, the product of $f(t)$ and $x(t)$ in time-domain is convulation in frequency domain, I tried to convolate $F(jw)$ and $X(jw)$. I am not getting success as the convulation is now involving dirac-delta function from $F(jw)$. I also tried Inverse fourier transform of $X(jw)$, but this looked weird to me because the Inverse Fourier transform now carries imaginary part also. Thank you!! Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: I believe that it's convolution and not convulation. In any case, a hint might be that $\delta_{\omega_0}* f (u)= f(u - \omega_0)$. So the convolution is not as bad as you think.

Comment: @Kore-N , Thank you. I think, I can solve it now. Can you please explain about Inverse Fourier Transform of real functions just like $X(jw)$.

Comment: There is not much to explain really. First of all, in your definition the first two cases do not seem to differ, making a computation difficult. In any case the Fourier transform mixes the real and imaginary part. Simple examples: $\mathcal{F}^{-1}(\delta_{k_0}) (x)= e^{-i\langle k_0, x \rangle}$ or $\mathcal{F}^{-1}(Id) (x)= i\partial_x \delta_0 (x)$ where $Id(k) = k.$ If you are studying quantum physics this should not be a surprise, since it's the absolute value of the Fourier transform which has an interpretation in terms of a  probability measure.